# loop through folder, copy and delete

Tags: file, batch-file

I have a folder That has subfolders as below : I was able to loop and copy the folder and subfolders from test1 to test 3.  But I want to extend the functionality by removing the each folder after copying
but am not able to instead is removing all the test 1 to test 3 folder.The test folder is just an example, the folders can be any name.

```
"C:\BACKUP_FDM_FILES\localbackup\test1"
"C:\BACKUP_FDM_FILES\localbackup\test2"
"C:\BACKUP_FDM_FILES\localbackup\test3"

pushd "C:\BACKUP_FDM_FILES"
for /f "tokens=*" %%G in ('dir /b /s /a:d ') do ( 
  echo Found %%G

  XCOPY  %%G  "C:\FDM\Upload" /e /s /y

  if errorlevel 0 (
    echo Copy  succesffully copied reason Files were copied without error and you can delete the content folder   
    rd "%%G\*"  /s /q
    mkdir "%%G"
  )
)
popD

pause
```

Comment: You may want to change your `for` to: `for /d %%G in (*) do (`. Use `rd` without wildcards: `rd /s /q "%%G"`

Comment: Yes, you are right I suppose not to put the wildcard there, but is still not working instead it removed all the folder without even creating it.

Answer (score 1):

If you resort to XCOPY, why not use the "successor" ROBOCOPY without any loop, deleting and re-creating the folder? Like in

```
robocopy "C:\BACKUP_FDM_FILES\localbackup\" "C:\FDM\Upload\localbackup" /s /e /COPYALL /dcopy:T /move
```

This will even keep the timestamp on the moved folder, and all attributes on moved files. Added benefit: you can use all the other helpful options of this command at no extra cost.

Comment: No, robocopy has been removing the parent folder and is not good especially and robocopy never fit into loop as well.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
"C:\BACKUP_FDM_FILES\localbackup\test1"
"C:\BACKUP_FDM_FILES\localbackup\test2"
"C:\BACKUP_FDM_FILES\localbackup\test3"

pushd "C:\BACKUP_FDM_FILES"
for /f "tokens=*" %%G in ('dir /b /s /a:d ') do ( 
echo Found %%G

XCOPY  %%G  "C:\FDM\Upload" /e /s /y

if errorlevel 0 (
echo Successfully copied now you can delete folder
popd
rd "%%G\*"  /s /q
mkdir "%%G"
)
pause
```

You are using **`pushd`** to go to *backup folder* so you need to use **`popd`** to go back to *parent folder*.

[SS64 - POPD](https://ss64.com/nt/popd.html)

Comment: I have it in my code, I just omitted it. it has ) pod D before pause

Comment: **`popd`** it should be before **`rd`** not after the code ends.
so that path switch to parent folder